# HTML5 looping 4 videos after end previous video not working in phoneGap android application

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, html5-video

I using PhoneGap for android application, HTML5 video tag for play video in application. the video is playing from phone SD card

**HTML:**

```
<video id="homevideo" width="100%" controls>
        <source  type="video/m4v" src="file:///mnt/ext_card/app/test1.m4v" >
</video>
```

**Script:**

```
var videoPlayer;
var video_count = 1;

document.addEventListener("deviceready", videoplay, false);
function videoplay(){ 
    videoPlayer = document.getElementById("homevideo");
     videoPlayer.play();

}
videoPlayer.onended = function(e) {
      video_count++;
      if (video_count == 4) video_count = 1;
      var nextVideo = "file:///mnt/ext_card/app/test"+video_count+".m4v";
      videoPlayer.src = nextVideo;
      videoPlayer.play();
}
```

also i used `addEventListener` for looping

```
videoPlayer.addEventListener("ended", function (){
       video_count++;
       if (video_count == 4) video_count = 1;
       var nextVideo = "file:///mnt/ext_card/app/advertisements/test"+video_count+".m4v";
       videoPlayer.src = nextVideo;
       videoPlayer.play();
}, false);
```

Only one video played, but it not looped... how can i loop the video one by one after previous video complate?

Comment: Did you solve [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17343470/sd-card-video-get-error-while-playing-in-phonegap-android) question yourself? If so I suggest you add an answer. :)

Comment: @Qben yes i got working with jQuery... i added answer check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got working this with jQuery...

i just tried with `jQuery` instant of `Javascript` its working now...

added JQuery library in `head`

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

and `script` used

```
$("#homevideo").bind('ended', function(){ 
  video_count++;
       if (video_count == 4) video_count = 1;
       var nextVideo = "file:///mnt/ext_card/app/advertisements/test"+video_count+".m4v";
       videoPlayer.src = nextVideo;
       videoPlayer.play();
});
```

Its working!!